# MySQL count likes and dislikes

Tags: mysql, sql

Guys i want to merge two tables. First table is `comments` and second table is `likes`. Likes contain likes and dislikes col `rate` (1 = liked, 2 = disliked)

So i want when i show all comments also i want to add two new cols `likes` and `dislikes` where i count how much likes and dislikes has one comment. I do that just for likes but i dont know how to do also for dislikes.

SO here is like table where i save likes:

```
like_id  item_id  account_id    rate  time                 host    
-------  -------  ----------  ------  -------------------  --------
    308      262           1       1  2016-03-18 13:45:16  (NULL)  
    309      263           1       2  2016-03-18 13:45:33  (NULL)  
    310      262           7       2  2016-03-18 14:23:49  (NULL)  
    311      262           8       1  2016-03-18 14:24:11  (NULL)
```

And here is comment table:

```
comment_id  item_id   content       account_id     time                 
-------     -------  ----------     ------------  -------------------
  308       262      Test comment      1          2016-03-18 13:45:16
```

So i want to do this result

```
comment_id  item_id   content    account_id     time    Likes  Dislike         
-------     -------  ---------    ------------  -----  -------- ------
 1           267      test comm        1                 4        2
```

**My query**

```
SELECT c.comment_id, acc.account_id, acc.account_firstname, acc.account_lastname,p.photo_name,p.photo_guid, COUNT(_like.item_id) AS likes
FROM pb_account_comments AS c
INNER JOIN pb_accounts AS acc ON acc.account_id = c.account_id
LEFT JOIN pb_account_photos AS p ON p.photo_id = acc.profile_picture_id
LEFT JOIN pb_account_likes AS _like ON _like.item_id = c.comment_id 
WHERE c.item_id = '2' GROUP BY c.comment_id
ORDER BY posted_date ASC LIMIT 0,3;
```

My query just count likes and this work good but how can i count and dislikes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the extra columns are needed for.  Normally, such columns should also be included in the `GROUP BY`.

A simpler version of your query just returns the information for each comment using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.comment_id,
       COALESCE(SUM(l.rate = 1), 0) AS likes,
       COALESCE(SUM(l.rate = 2), 0) AS dislikes
FROM pb_account_comments c INNER JOIN
     pb_account_likes l
    ON l.item_id = c.comment_id 
WHERE c.item_id = 2
GROUP BY c.comment_id
ORDER BY posted_date ASC 
LIMIT 0, 3;
```

Comment: Ah, you bit me to it.

Comment: Its posible to replace null value if like or dislike does not exist? Set any default value?